# Thunderstorm Frequency Depending on the Year

Tags: meteorology, climate-change, thunderstorm, storms

Why is it that some years have significantly more thunderstorms than others while other years have significantly less? For example, in 2008, there were 15 thunderstorm days in Asheville but above 40 in recent years. Why is this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too basic, shows no research, has been posted in different flavours multiple times and answers weren't accepted.

Comment: That was rude and not fair to have this question closed off. Meteorology is Earth Science

Comment: @RyanAmalfitano is it fair of you to never accept any of the very good answers you get,do you ever read the answers and follow the links to read the exellent explanations you can find there.people here lay down a lot of work and time to give good answers and all you do is to ask the same question over and over,most people ask questions to learn,what is your motivation for asking?